# Use Indy to perform an IPv6 reverse DNS lookup

Tags: delphi, dns, delphi-2010, ipv6, indy

I am using Indy to perform a reverse IPv4 lookup using the following code.

```
function ReverseDNSLookup(const IPAddress: String; const DNSServer: String; Timeout, Retries: Integer; var HostName: String): Boolean;
var
  AIdDNSResolver: TIdDNSResolver;
  RetryCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := FALSE;

  AIdDNSResolver := TIdDNSResolver.Create(nil);
  try
    AIdDNSResolver.QueryResult.Clear;
    AIdDNSResolver.WaitingTime := Timeout; 
    AIdDNSResolver.QueryType := [qtPTR];
    AIdDNSResolver.Host := DNSServer;

    RetryCount := Retries;
    repeat
      try
        dec(RetryCount);

        AIdDNSResolver.Resolve(IPAddress);

        Break;
      except
        on e: Exception do
        begin
          if RetryCount <= 0 then
          begin
            if SameText(e.Message, RSCodeQueryName) then
              Result := FALSE
            else
              raise Exception.Create(e.Message);

            Break;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    until FALSE;

    Result := AIdDNSResolver.QueryResult.Count > 0;

    if Result then
    begin
      Result := TRUE;
      HostName := ParseReverseDNSResult(AIdDNSResolver.QueryResult[0].RData);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(AIdDNSResolver);
  end;
end;
```

What do I need to change in order to make it compatible with IPv6?

I know I can use **getaddrinfo**, but in this particular case I need to contact the DNS server directly.

Comment: indy 10 has supprted ip v6 in its native format using resolver component since 2006, according to indy changelog.  What happens when you test the above code against an ipv6 host name?

Comment: @Warrent - You're correct. I'd incorrectly assumed that you needed to set some property when making the call to resolve. Looking at the Indy source I now see that it checks the type of address then formats the domain appropriately before sending it to the server. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Can you tell me any info abut the ParseReverseDNSResult function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do anything.  For `qtPTR` queries, `Resolve()` automatically detects whether the address is IPv4 or IPv6 and formats the query accordingly.