# Reading response from TIdDNSResolver?

Tags: delphi, dns, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10

I cannot find any simple examples of a DNS lookup using Indy 10's `TIdDNSResolver` component. They're all either for something I don't need (such as MX/SMTP), or are talking *terms* with no *code*. I have tried reading the result based on the few resources I can find, but don't know how I'm supposed to be reading the result.

Here's what I have so far...

```
uses
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdDNSResolver;

function TForm1.Lookup(const Name: String): String;
var
  X: Integer;
begin
  //DNS: TIdDNSResolver
  DNS.QueryType:= [qtA];
  DNS.Resolve(Name);
  for X:= 0 to DNS.QueryResult.Count-1 do begin
    if DNS.QueryResult[X].RecType = qtA then
      //Result:= DNS.QueryResult[X].RData;    <--- ????
  end;
end;
```

usage...

```
HostIP:= Lookup('www.google.com');
```

How do I read this response?

Comment: Perhaps [this question] will help? (Found by searching here on `[indy] TIdDNSResolver`). It asks about converting to support Ipv6, but shows using a reverse DNS lookup's return value. Don't know if it will help, but...

Comment: @Ken What question? There's no link in your comment...

Comment: Why not try this instead? http://www.delphidabbler.com/tips/25

Comment: Aargh! I hate it when I do that! :-) http://stackoverflow.com/q/8277903/62576 - it's the question itself (see the bottom half of the code).

Comment: @WarrenP indeed that it simple (only because the code's already written for me) but I'm already using Indy and I'm sure once this hurdle is passed it'll be much easier than using Winsock directly.

Comment: I wouldn't say that, but in this scenario making the request is very easy, it's just reading the response which isn't.

Comment: @WarrenP Plus it appears that linked code is only for IPv4, whereas Indy allows you to read either or.

Comment: The `QueryResult` collection item is an object of type `T<query type>Record` so all you need to do is typecast the item by the value of the `RecType` property. For instance [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/QLn8WKkg).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to typecast the [`QueryResult`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdDNSResolver_QueryResult.html) collection item to a specific [`TResultRecord`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TResultRecord.html) descendant depending on the [`RecType`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TResultRecord_RecType.html) property value of the item. From the [`Items`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TQueryResult_Items.html) property reference:

> Use casting to return an object reference that allows access to any
> properties or method specific to the descendant class associated with
> the value in TResultRecord.RecType.

The name pattern of the [`TResultRecord`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TResultRecord.html) descendant classes is like this:

```
T<DNS lookup type>Record
```

So in your case it would look like this:

```
for X := 0 to DNS.QueryResult.Count - 1 do 
begin
  if DNS.QueryResult[X].RecType = qtA then
    Result := TARecord(DNS.QueryResult[X]).IPAddress; // "A" lookup -> TARecord
end;
```

For a [`AAAA`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3596) lookup type it would be:

```
for X := 0 to DNS.QueryResult.Count - 1 do 
begin
  if DNS.QueryResult[X].RecType = qtAAAA then
    Result := TAAAARecord(DNS.QueryResult[X]).Address; // "AAAA" lookup -> TAAAARecord
end;
```

Example functions for IPv4 and IPv6 DNS lookups you may [`find here`](http://pastebin.com/QLn8WKkg).

Comment: This seems like a method that should be built into the QueryResult recordtype. (`AddressAsString()`)

Comment: @Warren, I don't think it would be helpful since just a few [`DNS records`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) contain address field.

Comment: Hmm. I really don't like the container-of-objects-requiring-cast-to-be-used. As Jerry has discovered, this is hardly a user friendly API.