# Read a hostname from webservice soap action rather an ip address HTTPRIO

Tags: delphi, soap, hostname

I must consume a webservice designed with a soap action with servername rather ip address. 
Ex: `<soap:address location="http://srv-envelope:8080/sijWs/SIJServices"/>`

I unknown that name in the net. But I Know its IP address.

How can I replace srv-envelope with its IP address in a HTTPRIO component in Delphi?

Is that possible or the web service must be rebuilt for publish the ip address?

Thanks.

Comment: the single IP can have a multiple HTTP servers over it. So in general - no, you can not. You might end up having a bunch of different domain names corresponding to the same single IP. And only one of them would be what you want... Or none.

Comment: In general that is called "reverse DNS lookup" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup.  Now, imagine that that SOAP server is only set to work for the *internal* network. So the outer *public* DNS servers would not know the name for the *internal SOAP* access. And while the public servers would tell you several public domain addresses to that IP - none of them would be the domain of the SOAP HTTP server. That is exotic case, but it is possible, there is no warranties....

Comment: Few links to reverse DNS lookup in Delphi - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277903 and http://www.delphigroups.info/2/4/219987.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724253 --- so you may TRY to get all the public domain names corresponding to that given IP and then to try HTTP SOAP connection using one of those domains after another. Hopefully one of those would work. But if not - then there is nothing to do unless you can reconfigure the service.